# MySQL One Column, two Foreign Key options

Tags: mysql

I have a database set up. In it are two tables, one containing `Events` with an `Event_ID` and the other containing `Venues` with a `Venue_ID`. These two tables have slightly different structures (events contain `date` and a `venue_name`, venues do not) I have descriptions for both events and venues, which do share the same structure. Is it possible to have one `descriptions` table that can reference either an `event_id` or a `venue_id`, or is it best to keep these seperate? Or is there a third alternative?

Venues+Events cant have multiple descriptions (referring to below comments)

Comment: `venue_name` is an attribute of *events*? Is that correct?

Comment: From my point of view, an event has a description and not the other way round. Thus, there should be a foreign key from event => description and ther could of course be another from venue => description

Comment: If venue has only one descpription, as I would imagine, I'd keep the `venue_description` in the venue table. I think also event description is unique to the event, so `event_description` belongs to the event table. If you have the one ultimate description for all or many events/venues you could consider third table for descriptions. Is this the case?

Comment: To @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: yes as an event is hosted at a venue (but this can be NULL)

They can have multiple descriptions for each venue or review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what your entities are trying to do, but to me (a native English speaker), an "event" is very different from a "venue".  An "event" is something that takes place at a particular point in time and place.  "Participants" can sign up for an "event".  A "venue" is a particular place.  These are very different entities.

There is a relationship between them.  As Alvaro points out in his comment, `venue_name` is not an appropriate attribute for `event`.  `venue_id` is the appropriate attribute, creating a link between the tables.

The answer to your question is that you could put descriptions into a single table, but it typically doesn't make sense (in most cases) to mix descriptions of different entities in a single table.  Normally, you would just add a `description` column to the tables where you want that attribute.

There are some circumstances where a single such table might be desirable.  If you are creating a multi-lingual database application and `description` is something that could be shown to users, then you might want to store all such strings in a single table to facilitate translation.